# Server installation in Datacenter

Tags: cisco, deployment

We have recently decided to deploy some of our servers to a datacenter. It is the first time i m deploying a server in a data center so it is little more different than i thought to what we have in the office. We will be using cisco catalyst 3750 switch to distribute bandwith to our servers. I was wondering if there are any step-by-step walkthrough of seting up the servers. Our dc providing us a deal with bandwith and colo. So the configuration they gave us follows;
Switch Port:

```
Ip Subnet
Subnet mask
Gateway
Config Type = Static/Gateway
Host Range = 
And name servers
ip range = *.*.*.2 - *.*.*.30
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it the same way as you set up servers in your office, except it sounds like they control the network, so you have to configure your servers to match. If that doesn't suffice, I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: In the office setup we have only one static ip. We just plugin the switch to the router and switch, rest is taken care of via dhcp. In this instance we will need to assign ips to switch interfaces for individual servers. I was wondering if there is a tutorial or walk through of some sorts for this type of setup.

Comment: No, you don't assign IPs to switch interfaces. If you don't understand how to assign a static IP to a server instead of using DHCP for everything (as you do with your existing servers), then either hire someone who knows what they're doing or purchase some services from your new datacenter host. - I don't mean to sound harsh, but from the way you asked the question, it's clear that you don't know much about system administration and you need it now. This site is great for questions and answers from which you can learn a lot, but you clearly need a jump start right now.